# Delete rows depends of colums values in another rows R

Tags: r

I have the following data frame with multiple observations:

---

```
     CHR            END         START          REF         ALT
      1            1445         1446            G           A
      1            1445         1446            A           G
      3            2787         2787            T           -
      3            2787         2787            -           T
```

And I want to delete rows if `REF` column is `-` and `ALT` column match `REF` column of another row while the other columns remains equal.

In my example thats the desired output:

```
     CHR            END         START          REF         ALT
      1            1445         1446            G           A
      1            1445         1446            A           G
      3            2787         2787            T           -
```

I'm not sure how to connect index of differentes rows

Always in the data frame the rows to delete follows the "mother" row

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>% 
  unite(tmp, REF, ALT, remove = F) %>% 
  mutate(tmp=strsplit(tmp, "_") %>% map_chr(function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse ="_"))) %>% 
  group_by(CHR, END, START, tmp) %>% 
  mutate(n=ifelse(grepl("-", tmp), 1:n(), 1)) %>% 
  filter(n == 1) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-tmp, -n)
# A tibble: 3 x 5
    CHR   END START REF   ALT  
  <int> <int> <int> <fct> <fct>
1     1  1445  1446 G     A    
2     1  1445  1446 A     G    
3     3  2787  2787 T     -
```

The idea is to add an identifier `tmp` with sorted `ALT`, `REF` values using a `strsplit` and `map` approach. Thus we can filter by duplicates using the counts of similar rows.

The data

```
d <- read.table(text=" CHR            END         START          REF         ALT

                1            1445         1446            G           A
                1            1445         1446            A           G
                3            2787         2787            T           -
                3            2787         2787            -           T", header=T)
```

Comment: Works fine! Thank you.

Comment: If the answer helped you please accept the answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work